# Tomcat9用のDevLoaderTomcat.jarの存在場所について

Tags: tomcat

以下の環境でTomcat9を使用したいと考えております。

環境
・Windows 10
・Oracle OpenJDK11
・Eclipse2020

開発用クラスローダーを使用したいので、Tomcat9用のDevLoaderTomcat.jarを探しておりますが、
見つける事が出来ません。
以下のURLから8.5用までのDevLoaderTomcat.jarはありましたが、
9用はありませんでした。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃればご教授いただけますでしょうか。

URL
https://sourceforge.net/projects/tomcatplugin/files/additional/

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [issue #16](https://github.com/tomcatplugin/tomcatplugin/issues/16)を見ると、自前でビルドする必要があるように思われます。[このプロジェクト](https://github.com/tomcatplugin/tomcatplugin/tree/master/net.sf.eclipse.tomcat.devLoader)をEclipseへインポートして、EclipseのProject Explorerで `jardescription.jardesc` をダブルクリックすれば生成できるようです。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。
ご連絡いただきました方法でjarファイルを作成する事が出来ました。
ただ、作成したjarファイルがTomcat9用のものかどうか判断がつかない状態です。

インポートしたプロジェクトを何もしないで「jardescription.jardesc」を実行しますと
8.5用のjarファイルとして作成されます。
また、Tomcatを起動すると以下のログが表示されるので、悩ましいところです。
[DevLoader] Starting DevLoader modified by e.siffert (August 04 2014) for Tomcat 8: Apache Tomcat/9.0.41

Comment: 出力されるjarファイル名がそのようになっているのは、単に[ここ](https://github.com/tomcatplugin/tomcatplugin/blob/master/net.sf.eclipse.tomcat.devLoader/jardescription.jardesc#L3)でそう定義しているからで、本当にTomcat8.5用のものかどうかとは無関係です。そして、実際にTomcat9に対応しているかどうかは、自身で試してみる他無いかと思います。そして、問題があるのならばissueを立てて修正してもらうのを待つか、自力で解決する必要があるでしょう。

Comment: やはりそうなんですね。自分で作成したjarをTomcat９上で動作するか確認してみます。ありがとうございました。